# Tortoise pydantic_model_creator method not contain ForeignKeyField of a model

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I have two models `Article` and `Tag`. `Article` has a foreign key from `Tag`

```
class Tag(MyAbstractBaseModel):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255, index=True)

class Article(MyAbstractBaseModel):
    title = fields.CharField(max_length=255, index=True)
    body = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    tag = fields.ForeignKeyField(model_name="Tag", related_name='article', on_delete=fields.CASCADE)
```

Here I would like to have my response checked by the following

```
@router.get("/article", response_model=get_serialize_pydantic(Article))
async def get():
    pass
```

Here is how I get the response model

```
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, create_model

def get_serialize_pydantic(models_obj: Type[Model], exclude: Tuple[str, ...] = None):
    my_model_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(models_obj)

    response_pydantic = create_model(
        __model_name=f"{models_obj.__name__}_response_pydantic",
        data=(Optional[List[my_model_pydantic]], Field(None, title="data")),
        __base__=BaseResponse)
    return response_pydantic
```

Problem is I only `title` and `body` in my response model, there is no `tag` in it. Anyone knows why?

Comment: _"... there is no `category` in it."_ Was that a typo? Did you mean there is no `tag` in it?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Yes that's a typo

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue from `pydantic` side. It's `pydantic_model_creator` of `tortoise` that causes the problem.

The solution is simple. Just init before serialisation.

```
from tortoise import Tortoise

Tortoise.init_models(["__main__"], "models")
my_model_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(models_obj)
```

https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib/pydantic.html#relations-early-init